# Oracle 7 ProC++ pre-compiled code

Tags: c++, oracle, compilation, oracle-pro-c

I am modifying an old DLL which uses Oracle 7 ProC++ precompiled code (SQLLIB18.LIB) and don't have any documentation for this release. No joy back from Oracle either.

Does anyone know what the numbers in the following compilation unit data represent?

```
static const short sqlcud0[] = {8,4130,2,0,0,1,189,0,6,49,0,11,11,0,2,7,68,66,95,78,65,77,69,3,97,0,0,3,5,0,0,3,97,0,0,3,97,0,0,3,97,0,0,3,3,0,0,3,5,0,0,3,5,0,0,3,5,0,0,3,97,0,0,};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I believe this is code produced by the Oracle Pro*C precompiler, and is not likely to be documented for the general public, even if you have the entire set of manuals. I did find a link to [V7.3.4 documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technology/documentation/oracle7.html) on Oracle's website. I don't suppose you still have the original Pro*C source code?

Comment: Many thanks DC. That link is very useful, will download. I did however manage to re-pre-compile the code with my changes in there after having sourced the proc.exe precompiler version I needed.